How to prove two power series are equal if they commute with same power series?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $R[[X]]$ be the ring of formal power series.
Let us consider $2$-tuple non-zero power series $U,V,W \in R[[X]]$, $X=(x,y)$,  that is,  $U,V,W \in (X R[[X]] \setminus \{0\})^2$ such that:

the Jacobians of $U$ and $V$ are equal at $0$ and both of the Jacobians have distinct eigenvalues. Moreover, the eigenvalues are not roots of unity.

$U$ and $V$ both commute with $W$, that is, $U \circ W=W \circ U$ and $V \circ W=W \circ V$

the Jacobian of $W$ at $0$ is non-singular


I would like to $U=V$. Are the above conditions sufficient to show it or do we need more?

My effort:
Let $U(x,y)=(u_1(x,y),~u_2(x,y))$, $V(x,y)=(v_1(x,y),~v_2(x,y)),$ and $W(x,y)=(w_1(x,y),~w_2(x,y))$.
Recall by assumption that $U,V,W$ can't contain any constant term, that is, $u_i, v_i, w_i$ starts with non-zero linear terms.
Let us denote the Jacobians (both are equal given) of $U$ and $V$ at $0$ by the $(2,2)$ matrix $A$, and the Jacobian of $W$ at $0$ is given by $(2,2)$ matrix $B$, then we can split the terms as follows:
$$U(X)=\underset{\text{linear terms}}{AX}+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{U^{(2)}(X)}+\underset{\text{cubic terms}}{U^{(3)}(X)}+(\text{higher degree terms}) \\
V(X)=\underset{\text{linear terms}}{AX}+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{V^{(2)}(X)}+\underset{\text{cubic terms}}{V^{(3)}(X)}+(\text{higher degree terms}) \\
W(X)=\underset{\text{linear terms}}{BX}+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{W^{(2)}(X)}+\underset{\text{cubic terms}}{W^{(3)}(X)}+(\text{higher degree terms}) $$
Since both $U$ and $V$ commute with the same function $W$ and since their ($U$ and $V$) Jacobians are equal, my claim is that $U=V$.
My idea is to assume that $U$ and $V$ agree up to quadratic terms but disagree at the cubic terms, then to show that the coefficients of the cubic terms of $U$ and $V$ vanish by comparing the terms using the given conditions: $U \circ W=W \circ U$ and $V \circ W=W \circ V$. This seems like a difficult task to compute in hand. So I am trying to approach an eigenvector argument as follows:
We can rewrite
$$U \circ W(X)=\underset{\text{linear terms}}{(AB)X}+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{(U \circ W)^{(2)}(X)}+\underset{\text{cubic terms}}{(U \circ W)^{(3)}(X)}+(\text{higher degree terms}) \\
W \circ U(X)=\underset{\text{linear terms}}{(BA)X}+\underset{\text{quadratic terms}}{(W \circ U)^{(2)}(X)}+\underset{\text{cubic terms}}{(W \circ U)^{(3)}(X)}+(\text{higher degree terms})
$$
Since we are given that $U \circ W=W \circ U$, we can compare both sides and obtained
\begin{align} &AB=BA \\ &(\text{some more relations comparing higher degree terms}) \end{align}
Similarly, the condition $V \circ W=W \circ V$ also gives $AB=BA$ and some other relations.
Since $A$ and $B$ commute, they can be diagonalised on the same basis. Their eigenvectors represent the same eigenspaces. In other words, both the functions $U$ and $V$ act or scale the vector $X=(x,y)$ in the same way at the linear level (degree 1 terms). Also, we have assumed that $U$ and $V$ agree upto quadratic terms, and therefor, trivially, $U$ and $V$ act on the vector $X=(x,y)$ in the same way.
To end the proof, we have to argue that the higher degree ($\geq 3$) terms of $U$ and $V$ can not be different. This should be true because $(1)$ $U$ and $V$ act on the vector $X=(x,y)$ in the same way upto quadratic level, $(2)$ $U \circ W=W \circ U$ and $V \circ W=W \circ V$.

I would appreciate any ideas or suggestions about the above approach or otherwise.

Since both Anne and I have provided counterexamples (Anne's being more general, as it's a counterexample to your revised problem), perhaps it's time to sit back, think carefully about what you'd like to ask, and pose a new question that's got some hope of having an answer that'll satisfy you.

Ah...indeed it does. Guess I need more coffee. :)

I suppose that the claim might be true if $W$ had a "rich enough" Jacobian (two distinct evalues???) at the origin, but I suspect that this isn't sufficient --- higher order terms in $U$ and $V$ might be able to "sneak around" that.

In Imre Lakatos's book Proofs and Refutations, you might want to read about "exception barring". Sometimes it's a good tool; often it's a rathole.

Again (as confirmed by John and my previous link), $0$ definitely belongs to the vector space $XR[[X]]$. Your two papers deal with a proper subset of it, by defining additional conditions. Look at their definitions of "stable" and "invertible" elements of $XR[[X]]$. Imo, you'd better do the same: choose a new name or notation for the subset(s) of "the standard $XR[[X]]$" which you want to consider.

@AnneBauval, alright, question edited further..

Consider
$$
U(x, y) = (x^3, y^3)\\
V(x, y) = (0, 0)
$$
The Jacobian of each at $(0,0)$ is the zero matrix.
Now consider
$$
W(x, y) = (x, y)
$$
Evidently $U$ and $V$ both commute with $W$.
But $U \ne V$.
So the thing you're trying to prove needs more hypotheses.

Sigh. Well, ya gotta love a chameleon question.

Yeah...Anne is right here. Things in $XR[[X]]$ 'have no constant term' in the sense that their constant term is zero. Unless you allow the possibility that $XR[[X]]$ contains zero, it ends up not having any nice algebraic structure (like being a group under addition!), and no one wants that. In general, saying things precisely is hard, sometimes harder even than proving things once you've stated them correctly. Even correctly reading correctly-stated stuff can be hard, as your remarks about the cited reference show.

Yup. I see nothing in that introduction that says $XR[[X]]$ doesn't contain a zero element. In fact, the notation is so well established that if someone meant that, they'd definitely say so in an introductory paragraph. But I'm not going to convince you, and you're not going to convince me, so we should stop.
